# Having a compiler in a OS

Tags: c, assembly

Hello I have been following the Cambridge Computer Labs: Baking Pi guide where you can build your own simple OS for the ARM CPU for the raspberry pi is assembly. My question is that how would you be able to implement a simple C compiler so i could run basic C programs in the OS (and how would you be able to even compile without the necessary headers? Would you need to implement them your self)

Answer (score 3):

Well, that's a ***HUGE*** task...

1. Write an ARM assembler. C programs are (usually) translated to assembly then assembled. You need this step anyway for the C compiler, so having a separate assembler is a good idea so you have another tool ready. Assemblers are relatively easy to write.
2. Write a C compiler (here the fun begins). This should transform C code into assembly.
3. Build a standard C library for your C program to use. This library has to interface with your OS. I suggest you that your OS follows some OS standard (like POSIX). This will make this part simpler.
4. Write a linker. This will take object files generated by the assembler and link them with corresponding libraries (if any).
5. ???
6. Profit

Comment: Just to fill in: "5. Give up, because none of this mess worked out."

Comment: You don't have to write it, you can just cross compile it on another machine.  C compilers have huge support for different cpu types. You take that compiler, get its source, and then just cross compile the compiler with the compiler that you're trying to cross compile...

Comment: maybe i could implement a little smaller language like BASIC-dialect like how how MS-DOS did?

Comment: @Magn3s1um I'm assuming he **does** want to write it. He also didn't have to write the OS, he could just use Linux and get away. I understand he wants to do all by him/herself

Comment: @EvanClark You don't have to implement the whole C language standard in your compiler at once, neither write the whole compiler in assembly. You can start writing a very basic subset compiler of C in assembly and then use this same compiler to write in C and extend the compiler. Once the C compiler is powerful enough, you can extend the library and write the linker.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile the c library into an assembly file for the ARM cpu on a different machine.  Then you're left with a binary file that you load into memory on the ARM machine, and you set the pc register to the start of the compiler if you want to start running it. You'll have to know the semantics of where pointers are located that point to your source files and such.  http://www.osdev.org/ has a lot of information about bootstrapping a c compiler.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765606/cross-compiling-for-arm-from-x86  This will tell you how to cross compile.  Since gcc is open source, you can easily port this to your r.pi.  The hard part is setting it up in the bootstrapper.

Comment: The C library does not only depend on CPU. It also depends on OS. It's not the same to do a Windows system call than a Linux system call. And I doubt his OS system calls are compatible with any modern OS. What he can indeed use is the C compiler code, given it does not use any system call (which I highly doubt).

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I am assuming he will be using a Linux Kernel/ his own C based kernel.

Comment: He's definitely not using Linux kernel, I think this is clear in the question :) And if he's using his own kernel, then we're back to starting point.

Comment: C-based OS? What's that? What do you mean?

Comment: Linux is written using the C language.  In order to port linux, what they do is they extend support for the  C language on another processor, and then cross compile Linux.  This is not the same for Windows, since it is written in C++.  This makes Linux a C-based Operating system and Windows a C++ one.  Mac OSX on the other hand is written in Objective-C, but originally Mac OS was written in C, making it once a C-based operating system, but now an Objective-C based operating system (with a lot of C components still in there).

Comment: Correct i will not be using the linux kernel this is just a simple little project and i will hope to use basic C/ASM micro kernel

Comment: @Magn3s1um I don't see how that's relevant. His OS is written in **assembly** not C. From OP: *"you can build your own simple OS for the ARM CPU for the raspberry pi **in assembly**"*.